# SQLite from API Call

Tags: python, sqlite, api

i am trying to insert a few thousands rows from the quandl site by making an API call and storing into an object call "data"
The structure of the data is simply date and price

```
import quandl as q
import sqlite3 as sq

token = "asdaasdewqrdfc"

data = quandl.get("WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD", authtoken=token)

conn = sq.connect("RVDB.db")

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Gold(PricingDate DATE, Price FLOAT)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO Gold VALUES('??','??')")

conn.commit()
```

Any ideas please ?

output[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6llGs.png)

Comment: Please show what `data` value is.

Answer (score 0):

The return from `quandl.get` is a Pandas dataframe. Use the Pandas utility function [`.to_sql()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to insert your data:

```
import quandl as q
import sqlite3 as sq

token = "asdaasdewqrdfc"
token = None

data = q.get("WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD", authtoken=token)

conn = sq.connect("RVDB.db")
data.to_sql('Gold', conn, if_exists='replace',
            dtype={'Date':'DATE', 'Price':'FLOAT'})
conn.commit()
```